# Am I serving my images incorrect, they are all shown rotated 90 degrees

Tags: php, html, image

I've once found this code to serve images from my server to the client:

```
$filename = $_GET["filename"];
if ($filename == null || strlen($filename) < 1){
    return null;
}

$fp = fopen($filename, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

When I run this php file via the browser (like call this script in the addressbar of the browser), a portrait image shows portrait.
But when I run this in an HTML file (I set the `src` of an `img` element dynamically) all portrait images are shown landscape (like rotated 90 degrees).

Should I include something in the response(-headers) that the image is landscape or portrait?

This is the way I load the image in the html:

```
document.getElementById('next').src = "image.php?filename=" + data;
```

This is what the request looks like when it's called from my html page and when the image shows correct:

[image]

And this is the incorrect version
[image]

I can see the headers differ, but does that make a difference? (besides I would know how to set the headers when I set the image source)

One thing I also noticed was that in both cases, when I rightclick and save the image, the filename is `image.jfi` which I think is a weird extension?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by in the browser and in html?

Comment: Check your images' meta data that describe the orientation.  I'm not sure if browsers respect this or not?

Comment: Difference between in the browser and in html is that *in the browser* I paste the link (like http://server/image.php?filename=xxxx) in the addressbar and then the browser shows an image. The *in html* part is where I use this hrml code to load the image in an `img` element : `document.getElementById('next').src = "image.php?filename=" + data;`

Comment: When I view just an image with exif orientation in the browser the orientation is respected.  Whereas if loaded via an img tag in a html document it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026441/is-there-a-way-to-tell-browsers-to-honor-the-jpeg-exif-orientation and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371408/3392762

Comment: I see the orientation is not respected. Howeve, I've never had this issue with any other picture on any of my websites.

Comment: An aside: your code may be a security concern. e.g. `?filename=/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Why not simply `src='/path/image-file-name.jpg'`?

Comment: @SougataBose The files are not in a location in the webserver, so I can't serve them from the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orientation was setted in Exif. Picture wasn't rotated phisicaly.
Image-viewer can to work with it but the browser in tag doesn't rotate it.

Your can rotate pictures on server by **imagemagick --auto-orient** http://imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#orient

You can also rotate it "on fly". Just get Exif info by **exif_read_data()** and rotate it if it has 3(180degree), 6(90CW), or 8(-90CCW) in **'Orientation'**

```
// dump the picture and stop the script
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$exif = exif_read_data($filename);
if (isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
   switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3: // 180 degree
            $rotate=imagerotate($source,180,0);
            break;
        case 6: // 90 CW
            $rotate=imagerotate($source,-90,0);
            break;
        case 8: // 90 CCW
            $rotate=imagerotate($source,90,0);
            break;
        default:
            $rotate=imagerotate($source,0,0);
            break;
    }
    imagejpeg($rotate);
    imagedestroy($source);
    imagedestroy($rotate);
} else {
    imagejpeg($source);
    imagedestroy($source);
}
```

But of course better to prepare all pictures once.

Comment: hmmm. I wonder if there is something wrong with the picture itself

Comment: It's not "something wrong". Just orientation wich devices set in exif. 
Image viewer undestands it, browser parser doesn't. That's all. 
Rotate all pictures by some tool (search "rotate by exif info") or do it on fly.